# window.onbeforeunload перестал работать при подключении angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Здравствуйте. У меня есть обработчик который удаляет пользователя из дати, если тут покинул или перезагрузил страницу, но при подключении к сайту angulara он никак не работает, я пробовал и в контроллер вставлять, и просто скриптом на старницу, и скриптом в файле js но никакой рекции. С чем это может быть связанно?

Comment: ты уверен, что твой код работает без ангуляра?

Comment: ну у меня этот проект был без ангуляра сделан, сейчас решил перенести, тогда обработчик лежал просто в глобальном скрипте подключенном к странице

Comment: Я не про это спросил.

Comment: когда проект был без ангуляра все работало

Comment: почему ты так думаешь? и почему думаешь, что с ангуляром - не работает

Comment: ну я же запускал этот проект кучу раз когда писал на обычном js

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62443/discussion-between-grundy-and-horchynskyi).